# Automatic turn on in android device

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks

I want to develop an app whereby one of it functionality is power on the device when it be powered off. I searched in developer documents but I find anything related to it.

There is a way to set your device to automatic power on? like a scheduled task?

Comment: How are you defining "off"? Do you mean that the screen is off but the device is still powered on? Do you mean that the device is fully powered down? Do you mean something else?

Comment: I edited the question. what I mean is powered off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the Android SDK itself for turning the device on from a fully-powered-off state. Some device manufacturers may have features for this, and some subset of those might have an API for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible on normal Linux machines with [RTC wake alarm](https://www.linux.com/learn/wake-linux-rtc-alarm-clock):

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm" 
$ sudo sh -c "echo `date '+%s' -d '+ 3 minutes'` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"
```

I have never tried this on Android, and if it does work, I'd imagine it requires rooting your device. Maybe that'd be good enough for your use case.

As @CommonsWare mentioned, some manufactures seem to support this as a setting. I'm not sure if they have an API, but that might also be worth researching. One of them seems to be [Samsung](http://www.trishtech.com/2014/06/schedule-android-power-on-off-automatically/).